# Is there anyway to make this python code better and more efficient?

Tags: python-3.x

I made a small python program to measure length of Username entered. If the length of Username is more than 6 characters, it prints "Username is valid", if length is less than 6 characters, it prints "Username must contain at least 6 characters" and if length is 0 (running the program without typing any characters), it prints "Username is required". Here is the code:

```
Name = input("Enter Your Name: ")

if(len(Name)>=6):
   print("Username is valid")
elif(len(Name)<6 and len(Name)>=1):
   print("Username should contain atleast 6 Characters")
else:
   print("Username is required")
```

I just want to know if I could do it better. Just a quick suggestion would do.
Also, this is my first time posting a question, so any suggestions to improve my question asking format would also be appreciated.

Comment: Some will argue that `elif 1 <= x < 6` is more readable, and I can't say I disagree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `len(Name)` is evaluated three times.

You can store the result in a variable, so that `len(Name)` is evaluated only once, and in the second and third occurrences you use that variable.

The performance difference is very negligible btw because it's a very small scale.

Another thing is variable names. In Python, we use snake_case to name variables by default for variables and UPPERCASED_TEXT for constants.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything "bad" about this simple program although I'd try to make it even more explicit and easier to read and understand. Something like this...

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")

if name != '':
    if len(name) < 6:
        print("username is not valid") 
    else:
        print(f"{name} is valid!")
else:
    print("username is required")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Since I'm a beginner, I'm having a bit difficulty understanding what you've done. Could you please explain it?

Comment: The code is more simpler and therefore easier to explain or easier for another person to quickly understand what is going on which is very important when you're working within the industry.